# How to implement the expectation of webpack modules?

Tags: javascript, html, web, webpack, import

Tell me if I'm doing the connection correctly, or there is a better way.
My `webpack` config:

```
let webpack = require('webpack'),
    path = require('path');

let srcPath  = path.join(__dirname, '/src/js'),
    distPath = path.join(__dirname, '/dist/js');

module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    cache: true,
    devtool: 'source-map',
    context: srcPath,
    entry: {
        app: './app.js',
        sellerModule: './sellerModule.js',
        account: './account/account.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: distPath,
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        library:["[name]"],
    },
   ...
};
```

Here are the subkeys in html

```
<script src="dist/js/app.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="dist/js/sellerModule.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now the main question. Seller module waiting for the event in the AP, I realized this as follows

```
class App {
    constructor() {
        window.addEventListener('load', this.OnLoadWindow.bind(this));
    }
    OnLoadWindow() {
        //here wait functions
        this._start();
    }

    _start() {

    }

    onReady(startFunc)
    {
        this._start = startFunc;
    }

}
```

And seller module

```
class SellerModule {

    constructor()
    {
        app.onReady(this.init.bind(this));
    }
...
```

It is right way? Sorry for the big code.